# Better way to send voice over a socket in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, tcp, voice

I made an AIR application that sends voice between two computers, this is the code:

```
package
{
    import fl.controls.List;

    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
    import flash.events.ServerSocketConnectEvent;
    import flash.media.Microphone;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.ServerSocket;
    import flash.net.Socket;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.system.System;

    public class VoiceCommunication
    {
        private var soundBytes:ByteArray;
        private var mic:Microphone;
        private var voiceReceiver:ServerSocket;
        private var voiceSender:Socket;
        private var mLocalIP:String;
        private var mRemoteIP:String;
        private var mPort:uint;
        private var sound:Sound;
        private var sample:Number;

        public function VoiceCommunication(localIP:String, port:uint)
        {
            mLocalIP = localIP;
            mPort = port;
        }

        public function startSendingVoice(remoteIP:String = null):void
        {
            mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();//2-null
            mic.gain = 100;
            mic.rate = 44;
            voiceSender = new Socket();//3-null

            mRemoteIP = remoteIP;//5-null
            mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);//1-remove eventlistener

        }

        protected function micSampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
        {
            if(mRemoteIP != null)
            {
                voiceSender.connect(mRemoteIP, mPort);
                while(event.data.bytesAvailable)
                {
                    sample = event.data.readFloat();
                    voiceSender.writeFloat(sample);
                }
                voiceSender.flush();
            }
        }

        public function startReceivingVoice():void
        {
            voiceReceiver = new ServerSocket;//2
            voiceReceiver.bind(mPort, mLocalIP);
            voiceReceiver.addEventListener(ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, handleConnection);//1
            voiceReceiver.listen();
        }

        protected function handleConnection(event:ServerSocketConnectEvent):void
        {
            var s:Socket = event.socket as Socket;
            s.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, handleData);      
        }

        protected function handleData(event:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            event.target.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, handleData);
            var s:Socket = event.target as Socket;
            soundBytes = null;
            soundBytes = new ByteArray();//3
            s.readBytes(soundBytes);
            playSound();
            s = null;
        }

        private function playSound():void
        {
            soundBytes.position = 0;
            sound = null;
            sound = new Sound();//5
            sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler, false, 0, true);//4
            sound.play();       
        }

        protected function playbackSampleHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
        {
            sound.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler);
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192 && soundBytes.bytesAvailable > 0; i++) 
            {
                sample = soundBytes.readFloat();
                event.data.writeFloat(sample);
                event.data.writeFloat(sample);
            }
            System.gc();
        }

        public function destroySender():void
        {
            mic.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);
            mic = null;
            voiceSender = null;
            mRemoteIP = null;
            System.gc();
        }

        public function destroyReceiver():void
        {
            voiceReceiver.removeEventListener(ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, handleConnection);//1
            voiceReceiver = null;
            soundBytes = null;
            sound.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler);
            sound = null;
            System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine and when I tried it, it did send the voice, but the problem is that sending the voice is too slow and gets split. So is there a better way to do it?

I rewrote it using datagram socket but that didn't work at all, the code:

```
package
{
    import fl.controls.List;

    import flash.events.DatagramSocketDataEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
    import flash.events.ServerSocketConnectEvent;
    import flash.media.Microphone;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.DatagramSocket;
    import flash.net.ServerSocket;
    import flash.net.Socket;
    import flash.system.System;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class VoiceComm
    {
        private var soundBytes:ByteArray;
        private var mic:Microphone;
        private var socket:DatagramSocket
        private var mList:List;
        private var mLocalIP:String;
        private var mRemoteIP:String;
        private var mPort:uint;
        private var sound:Sound;
        private var sample:Number;
        private var bytesToBeSent:ByteArray;

        public function VoiceComm(localIP:String, port:uint)
        {
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            mLocalIP = localIP;
            mPort = port;
        }

        public function startSendingVoice(remoteIP:String = null):void
        {
            mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
            mic.gain = 100;
            mic.rate = 44;
            mRemoteIP = remoteIP;
            mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);

        }

        protected function micSampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
        {
            var sample:Number;
            if(mRemoteIP != null)
            {
                while(event.data.bytesAvailable)
                {
                    sample = event.data.readFloat();
                    bytesToBeSent = null;
                    bytesToBeSent = new ByteArray();
                    bytesToBeSent.writeFloat(sample);
                    socket.send(bytesToBeSent, 0, 0, mRemoteIP, mPort);
                }
            }
        }

        public function startReceivingVoice():void
        {
            socket.bind(mPort, mLocalIP);
            socket.addEventListener(DatagramSocketDataEvent.DATA, handleData);
            socket.receive();
        }


        protected function handleData(event:DatagramSocketDataEvent):void
        {

            trace("Data inthere!");
            soundBytes = null;
            soundBytes = new ByteArray();//3
            event.data.readBytes(soundBytes);
            playSound();

        }

        private function playSound():void
        {
            soundBytes.position = 0;
            sound = null;
            sound = new Sound();//5
            sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler, false, 0, true);//4
            sound.play();       
        }

        protected function playbackSampleHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
        {
            sound.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler);
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192 && soundBytes.bytesAvailable > 0; i++) 
            {
                sample = soundBytes.readFloat();
                event.data.writeFloat(sample);
                event.data.writeFloat(sample);
            }
            System.gc();
        }

        public function destroySender():void
        {
            mic.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);
            mic = null;
            mList = null;
            mRemoteIP = null;
            System.gc();
        }

        public function destroyReceiver():void
        {
            soundBytes = null;
            sound.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler);
            sound = null;
            System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:

The code after modification:

```
package
{
    import fl.controls.List;
    import flash.events.DatagramSocketDataEvent;
    import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
    import flash.media.Microphone;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.DatagramSocket;
    import flash.net.Socket;
    import flash.system.System;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class VoiceComm
    {
        private var mic:Microphone;
        private var soundBytes:ByteArray;
        private var sample:Number;
        private var sound:Sound;
        private var socket:DatagramSocket;
        private var mLocalIP:String;
        private var mPort:uint;
        private var mRemoteIP:String;
        private var receivedBytes:ByteArray;

        public function VoiceComm(localIP:String, port:uint)
        {
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            mLocalIP = localIP;
            mPort = port;
        }
        //destroyers:

        public function destroySender():void
        {
            mic.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, sampleData);
            mic = null;
            soundBytes = null;
            System.gc();
        }

        public function destroyReceiver():void
        {
            socket.removeEventListener(DatagramSocketDataEvent.DATA, playSound);
            receivedBytes = null;
            System.gc();
        }

        //sending part
        public function startSendingVoice(ip:String = null):void
        {
            mRemoteIP = ip;
            mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
            mic.rate = 44;
            mic.gain = 100;
            mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, sampleData);
        }

        protected function sampleData(event:SampleDataEvent):void
        {
            soundBytes = new ByteArray();
            while(event.data.bytesAvailable)
            {
                var sample:Number = event.data.readFloat();
                soundBytes.writeFloat(sample);
            }
            if(mRemoteIP != null)
            {
                event.data.position = 0;
                socket.send(soundBytes, 0, event.data.length, mRemoteIP, mPort);
            }
        }


        //receiving part
        public function startReceivingVoice():void
        {           
            socket.bind(mPort, mLocalIP);
            socket.addEventListener(DatagramSocketDataEvent.DATA, playSound);
            socket.receive();
        }

        protected function playSound(event:DatagramSocketDataEvent):void
        {
            trace("got data!");
            receivedBytes = new ByteArray();
            event.data.readBytes(receivedBytes);
            receivedBytes.position = 0;
            var sound:Sound = new Sound();
            sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler, false, 0, true);
            sound.play();
        }

        protected function playbackSampleHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
        {
            trace("Playing Sound...");
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192 && receivedBytes.bytesAvailable > 0; i++) 
            {
                var sample:Number = receivedBytes.readFloat();
                event.data.writeFloat(sample);
                event.data.writeFloat(sample);
                System.gc();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are reconnecting the socket each time the mic sends a sample?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the cause of making the sound sending slow..

Comment: Perhaps it isn't what is making it slow, but still you should simply establish the socket connection once and let it persist.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely the source of the issue: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3111816. The TCP Nagle Algorithm. What this basically does is, when you're writing a bunch of small chunks of data to the socket, instead of sending them all out individually it will hold them back and pool them together in order to send a single "full" packet rather than tons of small ones (which leads to a greater, constant load on the network).

If possible, re-write using Datagram sockets instead. To my knowledge there is currently no way to disable the Nagle algorithm in Flash.

**Update**

A couple things after looking at your code in depth: The first is that you're writing each byte one at a time to the TCP socket. Don't do that, write the entire bytearray and flush it.

```
if(mRemoteIP != null)
{
    voiceSender.connect(mRemoteIP, mPort);
    voiceSender.writeBytes(event.data, 0, event.data.length);
    voiceSender.flush();
}
```

That may solve the issues you're having. If not, the reason why your UDP version is for two reasons. The first is that again, you're writing one byte at a time and sending but more important, you're telling it not to write the data to the socket at all. This line is the culprit:

```
socket.send(bytesToBeSent, 0, 0, mRemoteIP, mPort);
```

Note the third paramter, "0". That parameter is the amount of data from the supplied bytearray that should be written to the socket. So you're essentially saying, don't send anything. Change the code like so:

```
if(isConnected == true)
{
    event.data.position = 0;
    localSendingSocket.send(event.data, 0, event.data.length, remoteIP, remotePort);
}
```

Let me know if this works out for you. In the meantime I'm re-writing your code based on these suspicions so if I manage to get a project compiled and working before you, I'll post the project files here.

Comment: I used the Datagram socket, but this didn't send the voice at all!

Comment: See above, the code using Datagram socket but that didn't work! I mean no voice was sent or received.

Comment: I'll go over your datagram code later because I'm going to have to set this up on two machines to test. I'll get back to you.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on some errors I've found in your code. Let me know if these changes work out for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm gonna try this.

Comment: I did what you told me and that didn't work! Well, it sent just for less than a second and then it stopped sending the voice. I want also to tell you that when we pass "0" as a third argument for the send function means that we are going to write the whole ByteArray, I saw this in the send() documentation.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test this yet on two comps. When I have a chance and get something working I'll update my answer.

Comment: OK, I'll be waiting for your answer

Comment: Did u find a solution or not?

Answer (score 0):

use the (OS) Red5 server.

http://www.red5.org/

the blurb:

"Red5 Media Server 1.0 delivers a powerful video streaming and multi-user solution to the ©Adobe ©Flash Player and other exciting client technologies. Based on Java and some of the most powerful open source frameworks, Red5 stands as a solid solution for business of all sizes including the enterprise.
Red5 includes support for the latest multi-user API’s including NetConnection, NetStream and SharedObject’s while providing a powerful RTMP / Servlet implementation. In addition to support for the RTMP protocol, the application server has an embedded Tomcat Servlet container for Java EE Web Applications. Application development draws additional benefits from the Spring Framework and Scope based event driven services.
By using the Open Source Red5 Media Server, you are developing with a truly open and extensible platform that can be used in Video Conferences, Multi-User Gaming and Enterprise Application Software.
Happy Coding and enjoy our powerful free community server"

Comment: I want both computers to connect directly without a server-side

Answer (score 0):

Where not use Adobe Cirrus (formerly Stratus to create a peer2peer application instead of the socket?